# Spatial interpolation for scattered data

Tags: java, android, geospatial, interpolation, kriging

I have a list of metars points (latitude, longitude, sea level pressure) and need to interpolate the pressure.

Suppose I want to iterpolate the red point (on the kriging side of the image bellow) using the known measurements in the list of metars (the black points in the image).
[image]

Can I use ordinary kriging to interpolate only one point? And how?

I don't need a grid with all the interpolated points.

(I'm developing for android with java.)

I just don't understand the formulas in [Kriging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging).

[Here](http://geomatica.como.polimi.it/corsi/statistical-analysis/TrattamentoII_Es.5_FILTERING.pdf) they calculate only one point using kriging on pages 27-28.

See section 2.1 from this [paper](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fams.confex.com%2Fams%2Fpdfpapers%2F161982.pdf&ei=g-5aVYSMNcz-UpXngNAP&usg=AFQjCNENaKoe31DpjLBxsNn9y-JOLeRwOg&sig2=Cyag5AzjI-jhYNiiBoZgnA&bvm=bv.93564037,d.d24&cad=rja).

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Are you looking for a Java implementation of Kriging (which can do what you are asking)?

Comment: I'm more concerned about how to interpolate only one point using the ordinary kriging method, but if someone could give me a java implementation of kriging that interpolate only one point, that is even better.